# Post IDs are not quoted in dependent mix batch-request of FQL and Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-batch-request

I'm using batch requst:

*query1*: Get page posts with Graph API (and other fields and comments)

*query2*: Using the `{result=query1:$.data.*.id}` from *query1* to get all posts IDs and to get in FQL the `user_likes` fields.

The problem is `{result=query1:$.data.*.id}` are post IDs list that not quoted
and because of that I get error:

```
(#601) Parser error: unexpected '_502089509911778' at position
```

Is there way to fix this ?

```
@"SELECT post_id,like_info.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id
in ({result=query1:$.data.*.id})";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible that you just keep the *query1* separate, and write *query2* as follows:

```
SELECT post_id,like_info.user_likes FROM stream WHERE source_id={page_id} AND actor_id={page_id}
```

where {page_id} is the PageID of your interest?